# Server not available at new Route53 CNAME

Tags: amazon-web-services, cname-record, a-record, amazon-route53

I have a static website (www.example.com) hosted through AWS S3 and Route53. The customer registered their DNS through GoDaddy; www.example.com traffic works great.

On that static website is a "contact me" form that I want to point to "office.example.com". I want the "office.example.com" URL to resolve to an EC2 instance.

I added a `CNAME` record for "office.example.com" to Route53, using the Elastic IP for the relevant EC2 instance:

[image: settings for my new AWS Route53 CNAME record]

**After saving the altered recordset, I attempt to navigate a browser to http://office.example.com, but I'm getting a "Server Not Found" error. Do I need to be patient and wait for the DNS to propagate, or have I configured the Route53 recordset incorrectly?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That isn't how a `CNAME` is used.  If the resource record you are creating needs to reference a target that is accessed via lookup of *another* hostname, you use a CNAME.  If the target is an IP address, you need an `A` record.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record

Comment: Switched it to an `A` record with no other changes. Immediately browsing to the URL  didn't work, but after waiting a few minutes it gets me through. Thanks for the assist.